# Google speech to text gives very late response in mobile device

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm using google speech to text converter and it works fine on desktop, but in mobile devices, it gives a very late response. Even on google's example page, it gives a late response.

I'm using live streaming.

In the response, google returns is_final keyword which is used to identify if its the final response from google or not, which is coming very late, sometimes around after 90 seconds.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = 'en-US'; //en-US

var request = {
    config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
        languageCode: languageCode,
        enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
        model: "default",
    },
    interimResults: true, // If you want interim results, set this to true
};
```

Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: You can try to resample and send 8khz compressed, that will save you a lot of delay.